# Bounded, divergent series with terms approaching zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there an example, or proof that one cannot exist, of a sequence of real numbers $a_n$ such that

(1) $a_n\rightarrow 0$ (perhaps non-monotonically),

and

(2) the sequence of partial sums $\sum_1^N a_n$ are uniformly bounded,

but the sum $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ diverges?

Condition (1) prevents things like $a_n = (-1)^n$, while condition (2) prevents things like $a_n = 1/n$.

Comment: For a simple example, take one $+1$, followed by two $-1/2$'s, four $+1/4$'s, eight $-1/8$'s, sixteen $+1/16$'s, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $$a_n=\sin{\sqrt{n+1}}-\sin{\sqrt n}.$$